# ms-access: is it possible to zoom in design view?

Tags: microsoft-access

does anyone know if there is an option to zoom in design view in access 2007

Comment: I think generally developers, maybe not hard core developers, are messing around with designs in Access, so thus not a superuser question.  Unless he's doing a program to track his mp3's or something.

Comment: It's not a programming question. It's a "use of user interface" question. It's not even a question about designing a UI for a custom Access application. I can't see how questions about how to use an application belong on SO at all.

Answer (score 8):

Although a good answer (changing screen resolution) was already given and accepted, I will point out that in Windows 7, you could press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to start the built-in Magnifier.  This will let you temporarily zoom in and out (by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>−</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

While it would be a very nice feature, MS has never seen fit to provide it. However, you might want to check out Layout view, which is quite useful. It allows you to design the report while viewing real data. I just checked A2010 and I don't see any Zoom there, either.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Windows Magnifier tool. It's not the perfect solution, but you don't have to change your screen resolution, and you can view the zoomed window while still seeing the normal-sized application, similar to the thumbnail view when zoomed in MS Paint.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to zoom the screen is to increase your font size.  This is the only thing I have found that works for me!  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can always change your screen resolution for when you're working in it.  That would make the text larger.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into View->Print Preview, there will be a **Zoom** tab on the top bar. Click on **Zoom**, and define your *Zoom %*.

Unfortunately, when you close Print Preview, it goes back to normal..

I'm honestly just surprised you can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Scroll Up.

Answer (score -2):

For Access 2013, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> opens the Item Zoom dialogue box.